# Angular.uppercase() is not a function in Angular 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I added a js file, ui-grid.js and it uses a function uppercase() which is not recognize. All other angular function are working in my project, but when I include the js file, I have this error.

I checked if ui-grid.js is loaded after angular.js and it is.

I really don't understand why

Comment: We neither understand really why, because you didn't post any code and thing you've done so far :)

Comment: @BelminBedak https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=angular.uppercase&type=

Comment: @BelminBedak I too encounter the same issue. just include angularjs v 1.7.x and ui-grid v4.6.1 and add `<div id="grid1" ui-grid="main.gridOptions1" class="grid"></div>` to replicate the error. I had to downgrade the angularjs version to 1.6.8 to fix. It looks like the error has been addressed in latest release, i.e.  v4.6.3 of UI-grid. see this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/pull/6730 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ui-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid) is not compatible with Angular 1.6

> UI-Grid is currently compatible with Angular versions ranging from 1.2.x to 1.4.x.

Comment: We use it with 1.5.8 without any problems, though.

Comment: I just replaced angular.uppercase() bu toUppercase() it works !

Answer (score 6):

Updating angular-ui-grid to 4.6.3 solved this for me, on Angular 1.7.4.